# How to run a SSH command from www-data

Tags: php, ssh

I need to run this command from php/nginx (www-data)

```
shell_exec("ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$host 'ps axo pid,cmd'")
```

But get this error

```
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/root/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: Create this directory and make it owned by `www-data`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a permission issue while the **www-data** user doesn't have write permission to **/var/www/.ssh** directory (/var/www is default home folder for www-data user).

The issue should resloved by run following commands

```
mkdir /var/www/.ssh
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/.ssh
```

Comment: it does work, btw

Answer (score 0):

Please use "phpseclib" for a PHP SSH implementation.
Below is the example:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.example.com');
if (!$ssh->login('uname', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Comment: Then take it as a parameter. and this code is run on form submit.

Comment: Have a look at http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/auth.html, other auth types are also supported

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Net_SSH2' not found in - this is the standard Error nearly EVERY user gets ... can anybody help?

Answer (score -2):

its permission error. you need to add - 'sudo' before command.

```
sudo shell_exec("ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$host 'ps axo pid,cmd'")
```

Comment: oh yes!...sorry my bad.